# EDISMAX - 0 weight for QF field

Tags: solr, edismax, dismax

I came across an example EDISMAX query with 0 weight assigned to a field in `qf`.

Example: 
Fields in index: `title, body, keywords`

`qf = title^100 body^0 keywords`

I understand providing no boost indicates default boost of 1. I however do not understand what it means to assign a boost factor of 0.

Thank you.

Comment: If you append `&debugQuery=true` to your URL you'll get a lot more information about how the score is calculated - it's a good way to start to analyze something like this.